# Django Apache MsSQL connection timeout

Tags: sql-server, django, apache, mod-wsgi, pyodbc

I am trying to Django with MS SQL Server on CentOS 7 using Apache mod_wsgi. I'm able to run the Django app using `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` and navigate to my grappeli admin page.

However, when I run using Apache, the home site loads up just fine but then I get `OperationalError: ('HYT00', u'[HYT00] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')` when I attempt to navigate to the admin page.

It's strange that runserver would work using the same virtualenv that I'm pointing my apache config at.

pip freeze:

```
Django==1.11.10
django-grappelli==2.10.2
django-pyodbc==1.1.3
django-pyodbc-azure==1.11.9.0
pymssql==2.1.3
pyodbc==4.0.22
```

contents of /etc/httpd/conf.d/django.conf:

```
<Directory /opt/measurement_app/measurement_app>
   <Files wsgi.py>
       Require all granted
   </Files>
</Directory>
WSGIDaemonProcess measurement_app python-path=/opt/measurement_app:/opt/measurement_app/measurementenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup measurement_app
WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/measurement_app/measurement_app/wsgi.py
```

settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'MEASUREMENT',
        'HOST': ****,
        'PORT': 1433,
        'USER': ****,
        'PASSWORD': *****,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
            'dsn': 'app-sqldb',
            'use_legacy_datetime': True,
        }
    }
}
```

odbcinst.ini

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.0.so.1.1
UsageCount=1
```

odbc.ini

```
[app-sqldb]
Driver = ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Description = SQL Server 2012 DenSQL
Server = ****
instance = MEASUREMENT
Database = MEASUREMENT
Port = 1433
Trace = Yes
TraceFile = /tmp/odbc.log
```

Comment: I'm wondering if it is a conflict in your `virtualenv` - you shouldn't need `django-pyodbc`, only `django-pyodbc-azure`. Try removing `django-pyodbc` as a starting point?

Comment: You may be onto something. When I uninstalled django-pyodbc the django dev stopped working and became like Apache. @FlipperPA do you think it could be something else?

Comment: Since you are on CentOS, it is possible the SELinux configuration is restrictive and blocking you in some way. The Apache user often has a more restrictive profile.

Comment: That solved it! @GrahamDumpleton you are truly an Apache wizard

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that my SELinux configuration was restrictive and was blocking the connection. The solution was to edit my `/etc/selinux/config` and set

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

then `reboot`

The mod_wsgi documentation mentions that SELinux has the potential to cause some issues in:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#secure-variants-of-unix

Comment: Except that you shouldn't disable it. You should work out how to configure it to allow what is required.

Comment: Definitely, I'm just so excited this is working right now