# Add to Apache Path

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm running apache, mod_wsgi, django, and mssql.

I have the following line in my .bashrc: `export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"`

I had Django print the current value of `os.environ['PATH']` to a template and it returned.

`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`

How do I add to whatever path Apache is using?

I've already tried `sys.path.append('/opt/mssql-tools/bin')` in my `wsgi.py` file.

Comment: Provide the exception details you are getting when your application fails. The answer given below about changing ``PATH`` is correct for what you asked, so obviously your actual problem is different to what you think it is.

Comment: To the extent that running MS SQL on Linux is "right", Daniel's answer is right.  This may be a XY problem... what error message are you getting?  If you run manage.py shell as your user but with the line in bashrc disabled, do you get the same error?

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to explain better what I'm seeing. My problem stems from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48792764/django-apache-mssql-connection-timeout.

I am able to connect to a database using Django dev but apache keeps timing out. The only difference I am able to see is that of the `PATH` apache is using. I was thinking that apache could not connect becuase it lacks access to those binares.

Answer (score 0):

Apache does not run as your user so editing your .bashrc is pointless.

Since you know how to display the value of `os.environ['PATH']`, you should be able to modify it too:

```
os.environ['PATH'] += ":/opt/mssql-tools/bin"
```

(I'm not quite sure what the point of this would be, though; are you calling out to external binaries within your Django code? And if so why don't you use the full path to the binary?)

Comment: `os.environ['PATH'] += ":/opt/mssql-tools/bin"` adds to a local string variable and wouldn't help in the least bit. In order for Django to connect to SQL Server it needs `/opt/mssql-tools/bin`

Comment: Apologies, I didn't understand how os.environ interface really worked. Daniels answer added to the path variable